# Is the Airbus Beluga's safety record comparable with the record of other Airbuses?

Tags: safety, airbus, airbus-beluga

Upon first sight, to the uneducated eye, the [Airbus Beluga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_Beluga) looks incredibly 'un-aerodynamic'. Is the Beluga just as safe as other Airbus models?

Comment: It might be even safer. No hull loss.

Comment: I don't see how you can get a reduction on allowable (technical) risk from the certification authorities for a large aircraft. And @vasin1987 has said that there have been no hull losses.

Comment: @jjack The Beluga is [certified](https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/EASA_R-TCDS_EASA.A.014_Issue6.pdf) as a restricted category aircraft. As EASA puts it, "This is intended for aircraft that cannot comply with all applicable airworthiness requirements because they are specifically designed for a special purpose..."

Comment: What are you worried about happening?

Comment: A Beluga apparently had a cockpit wiring fire yesterday... The Beluga TCDS does note restricted conditions about stalls, operational speeds, gust tolerance, and a stick pusher (not present on the base model), so the question whether there are aerodynamic compromises is probably yes.

Comment: @zeta-band Well... an accident I guess! :)

Comment: OK, @Cloud, what did you do?

Comment: @Sean What do you mean? I didn't die on the flight so that's a bonus... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a history of oversize airplanes for transport. One of the earliest was the Pregnant Guppy and its successor the [Super Guppy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aero_Spacelines_Super_Guppy)

[image]
<sub><sup>By NASA/Tom Tschida - http://www.nasa.gov/centers/dryden/multimedia/imagegallery/Guppy/EC00-0212-2.html (image link), Public Domain, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=32895741</sup></sub>

Boeing operates its own variant, the [Dreamlifter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_Dreamlifter)

[image]
<sub><sup>By scott wright (originally posted to Flickr as n780ba) [CC BY 2.0 ( http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0 )], via Wikimedia Commons</sup></sub>

To my knowledge, none of these (including the Beluga) have had any safety incidents (although the Dreamlifter did [once land at the wrong airport](https://www.wired.com/2013/11/dreamlifter-wrong-airport/)). I'm not sure if there's any conclusions on safety to draw from, however, as there aren't a lot of these around, as they primarily transport large materials (like aircraft parts).

Comment: There's definitely been Beluga [safety incidents](http://avherald.com/h?search_term=A3ST&opt=0&dosearch=1&search.x=0&search.y=0). I do remember something falling off it 10+ years ago.

Answer (score 2):

The Beluga, or other bulk-freight carriers, such as the Guppy variants or the Dreamlifter, are as aerodynamic as they can be, regarding the contrains on cargo volume. So, they are unusually shaped/large, yet they are not un-aerodynamic.

As for the safety record, there is only a small number of [Belugas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_Beluga). So, the safety statistics is not comparable to a large-number type, e.g. A300.
Furthermore, the per-plane, per-year mileage is much larger for the common passenger carriers that for the bulk-cargo carriers. So, a single A300 clocks much more miles in a year than a Beluga.

To conclude, statistics becomes more and more significant the larger the involved sample is. Statisticians might argue, whether a sample of 5 (hulls, in the case of the Belugas) is a sample at all (strictly statistically/mathematically speaking).

Comment: To add, all belugas owners can certainly do prime maintenance on their air carriers and give prime training to the pilots. Both major factors in accident prevention.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if a single A300 clocks more miles each year than the entire Beluga fleet.